# Do most phones default to Automatic Date and Time being on?

Tags: date-and-time

I guess this is really a question about carriers in the US since I suspect they control these types of default settings.

Do most Android phones default to have "Automatic" Date & Time setting on?

Someone reported SSL certificate failures in an app and the root cause was the phone's clock was set to 2004. I'm trying to figure out if this is a common occurrence. If most phones are set to automatic date & time I won't worry too much. If phones don't automatically have synchronized clocks, I suspect these type of error would be more common.

[image]

Comment: In my experience, the automatic date & time settings are on by default, and time zone detection doesn't work. If I leave my devices with the default settings, they are always 2-3 hours behind since my time zone is UTC+2 (or +3 during DST).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  No, I don't have a source. :P